# How can I play sound when not logged in on Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, pipewire

System: Ubuntu LTS 22.03 and 23.04 tested.
I only hear sound after i did login into the login manager (gnome), so i cannot play anything from terminal without login into Gnome...
I have a Python Systemd Daemon which is working fine, but it cannot play audio because it only sees "DUMMY OUTPUT" as sound devices, see "wp-ctl status" shows
SINK: "DUMMY OUTPUT

After i login into gnome, i can hear the daemon playing the files.
And wp-ctl shows after login:

```
Audio
 ├─ Devices:
 │      41. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │      43. Built-in Audio                      [alsa]
 │
 ├─ Sinks:
 │  *   45. Built-in Audio Analog Stereo        [vol: 2.00]
 │
 ├─ Sink endpoints:
 │
```

I did install ubuntu via server iso then installed ubuntu-desktop. In the LTS ubuntu i have the same problem as with the 23.04 version.

On startup i also setup the volume loud, but that is **not** the problem:

```py
subprocess.call(['wpctl', 'set-volume', '@DEFAULT_AUDIO_SINK@', '2'])
file = ' /home/backupbox/backupbox/media/startup_completed.mp3'
os.system('play ' + file)
```

I expect: Play audio mp3 files from my python systemd daemon without logging into gnome.